# Does the cell release the empty capsids?

Tags: dna, virology, cell-membrane, coronavirus

The virus via the spike of the capsid connects to a receptor in a cell, then the DNA enters the cell wall. 
My question is what happens to the capsid - does it stay connected to the receptor or is getting loose.
(e.g disconnected from the cell).

Comment: Which virus, and where did you read this? Please provide details — preferably with a link — to your source so that we can try to help you.

Comment: I mean any virus. Does it connect to a receptor? After the DNA gets in, what happens to the capsid?

Comment: But only certain viruses have spikes, and different viruses use different strategies to enter cells, and those surrounded by a membrane will behave differently to those that don’t, and how long is a piece of string. I suggest you read a little about viruses in general (try Wikipedia), and then about coronaviruses, if that is your interest (try the links on Meta). However it is my understanding that decapsidation generally occurs within the cell, and the capsid proteins are left as litter.

Comment: I understood that this is true only for a certain type of viruses namely the bacteriophages. In that case can their capsids gained from a culture be used to induce antibodies?

Comment: If your real concern is raising antibodies to capsid proteins, that is a different question. If your interest in antibodies is for detection of viruses or as antiviral agents I suggest you might like to look at some of the links on the [Meta page](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses-how-to-ask-and-external-resources) devoted to reputable sources of information about coronavirus.